# Add a way to search for chat messages posted in a certain time range

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

I would really love to find the first message I've ever posted in Stack Exchange chat, or, more precisely, a particular room.

<sub>Okay, I admit, I'm a bit nostalgic.</sub>

However, I can only search for messages containing a certain string, and my "recent" messages don't allow me to scroll back.

So, how do I find that piece of information? If that's not currently possible, please add some way to check that, e.g. by allowing to search transcripts where I participate all the way back in time.

---

There are many options that would not only allow me to find that particular message, but also improve the functionality of search as a whole, since currently, it's very limited.

- The *Replies* tab, which lets me choose "last month", but that's it. It would be easy to **include more time spans** to be selected there.
- The *Search* box, which lets me search for a particular string only, without wildcards. It'd also be easy to have it search for *all* messages, or alternatively only by **specifying a certain time range** to prevent excess.
- The *Transcript*, which could be **filtered by days where I participate** to make it easier to find interesting conversations even if they happened a while ago.

All in all, the tools are available in the backend and data, but it feels like they're still missing in the search feature open to the public.

Comment: 99% it was a variation of hello.

Comment: My money is on "Mr. Watson, please come here, I want you"

Comment: At the moment, you open up the room's transcript and keep clicking on the previous day until you don't see yourself talking anymore. But since that's a bit insane, you might want to turn this into a feature request.

Comment: Makes sense. I tried that but gave up once I saw that days were segmented into certain hours. Changed to a feature request. @Tim

Comment: Yeah, there isn't really a way to do that. If you ask nicely (and tell me which room) I can look it up though :) However, now that you've made it a feature-request, you'll have to also give actual reasons for this requested feature.

Comment: Boo :) Well, as it stands, search in chat is still very simplistic, at least from the end user's point of view. But it's not like the data isn't there. I've often looked for something on chat I just couldn't find because I had no way of specifying a time range. I guess it would make for a worthwhile addendum to the functionality of the chat engine to be able to search more precisely or retrace your own activity. @bal